# ElementClickInterceptedException in Python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to fix an `ElementClickInterceptedException` but my methods are not working. This is the [Link](https://www.betking.com/sports/s/event/p/soccer/england/eng-premier-league/0/0) I am using. When I click on the bars on the left side, before the game time, it opens something like a pop-up but it's on the same Window as shown in the picture... [image]
I am able to get the information needed on the page. Problem is after i close it by clicking on the `x`, it won't loop into the next one, it gives me the `ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element is not clickable at point because another element obscures it`. Mostly it does this on the second loop, but sometimes it passes the second and goes to the third but it's never passed the third loop. I tried using the wait and until but that didn't do any help, it only goes to `Timeout`. Here is the code I'm using for that.

```
#This fetch all the games I want to scrape for into a list of selenium objects
v1 = _.find_elements_by_class_name('trOddsSection')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
for __ in v1:
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
#__.find_element_by_class_name("col-0").click()
    
    
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//td[@class='col-0']")))
yyy = __.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@class='col-0']")

# This click gets the pop-up thing out
yyy.click()
    
v3 = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "divStatisticsWidget")))
    

sleep(3)

try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    # This is where I scrape what I want from the pop-up
    a = v3.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='right-container']/div[@id='content_headToHead']/div[@class='sectionFound']/div[@class='teamWinsDraws']")
    hm = a.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='teamHomeWins']/span[@class='teamName']/span[@class='resultsPerc']").text
    dr = a.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='teamDraws']/span[@class='teamName']/span[@class='resultsPerc']").text
    aw = a.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='teamAwayWins']/span[@class='teamName']/span[@class='resultsPerc']").text
    print("Here:\t\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(hm, dr, aw))
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        
    a_ = v3.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='right-container']/div[@id='content_headToHead']/div[@class='sectionFound']/div[@class='headToHeadHistory']")
    a__ = a_.find_elements_by_xpath(".//table/tbody/tr/td[@class='score']")
        print("H2H {}".format(a__[0].text))
        
except(NoSuchElementException):
    print("teamWinDraws class not found")

# This is where I close the pop-up window so I can move to next    
try:
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    sleep(4)
       
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//*[@class='close-icon']")))
    g_g = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@class = 'close-icon']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", g_g)
except(NoSuchElementException):
    print('close-icon not found')
except(TimeoutException):
    print('Timed out')
```

Anyone sees something I'm doing wrong or how to maneuver around this please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem Explanation

I see that, you are using `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` quite a lot in your script, this is basically an implicit wait, which one should set for one time, and it will be in effect till driver is not killed by internal/external way.

So, basically you can keep one `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` in your entire script, and remove all of them .

Also, we have to keep in mind that based on each row we should define the close button. I have made those corrections below.

## Solution

**Code :-**

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.betking.com/sports/s/event/p/soccer/england/eng-premier-league/0/0")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "cookieBoxClose"))).click()
except:
    pass

all_rows = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(@class, 'trOddsSection')]")
j = 0
for row in range(len(all_rows)):
    elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(@class, 'trOddsSection')]")
    time.sleep(2)
    elements[j].find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@class='col-0']").click()
    time.sleep(2)
    v3 = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@id, 'StatisticsWidget')]")))
    try:
        a = v3.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@id='right-container']/div[@id='content_headToHead']/div[@class='sectionFound']/div[@class='teamWinsDraws']")
        hm = a.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='teamHomeWins']/span[@class='teamName']/span[@class='resultsPerc']").text
        dr = a.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='teamDraws']/span[@class='teamName']/span[@class='resultsPerc']").text
        aw = a.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='teamAwayWins']/span[@class='teamName']/span[@class='resultsPerc']").text
        print("Here:\t\t{}\t{}\t{}".format(hm, dr, aw))

    except:
        print("teamWinDraws class not found")
        pass

    try:
        time.sleep(4)
        elements[j].find_element(By.XPATH, ".//following-sibling::tr//div[contains(@ng-click,'closeStatisticsBetradar')]").click()
        j = j + 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('close-icon not found')
    except TimeoutException:
        print('Timed out')
```

**Imports : -**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Program output :**

```
Here:       5 (20%) 6 (24%) 14 (56%)
Here:       10 (59%)    6 (35%) 1 (6%)
Here:       5 (33%) 4 (27%) 6 (40%)
Here:       8 (29%) 4 (14%) 16 (57%)
Here:       33 (61%)    14 (26%)    7 (13%)
Here:       12 (29%)    10 (24%)    19 (46%)
Here:       11 (33%)    12 (36%)    10 (30%)
Here:       28 (52%)    13 (24%)    13 (24%)
Here:       6 (23%) 4 (15%) 16 (62%)
Here:       7 (50%) 1 (7%)  6 (43%)
Here:       13 (45%)    8 (28%) 8 (28%)
Here:       5 (50%) 2 (20%) 3 (30%)
Here:       2 (11%) 3 (17%) 13 (72%)
Here:       17 (63%)    3 (11%) 7 (26%)
Here:       20 (59%)    7 (21%) 7 (21%)
Here:       10 (34%)    4 (14%) 15 (52%)
Here:       19 (37%)    19 (37%)    13 (25%)
```